# How to add a textbox in Assetportalbowser.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a web part, when clicked opens the assertportalbrowser. so how to add a textbox just above the "OK" and "Cancel" button in assetportalbrowser.

Note: Default behaviour of assetportalbrowser should not affect in other pages.

-Viggo

Answer (score 0):

The control used in such situations is called the AssetPicker (learn more about it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.asseturlselector.aspx).

If needed one could extend it with custom functionlity as described in http://www.theroks.com/custom-asset-picker-with-enhanced-urlfield/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but Asseturlselector control opens the default assetportalbrowser.aspx,what i need is something like shown in the screenshot.I have edited the default assetportalbrowser.aspx, I dont want to affect in all the pages. i want it only for particular page.

Comment: I have shared the image [IMG]http://i47.tinypic.com/33kawkw.png[/IMG]

Comment: My suggestion was to Extend the actual control as it is not recomanded to change the default - any future updates would override your changes.